# LDAP Authentiation

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using a javascript library to for LDAP authentication. It works:

example:

```
const opts = {
  server: {
    url: 'ldap://192.168.0.32',
    bindDN: 'ldapAdmin',
    bindCredentials: 'password123',
    searchBase: 'DC=mycompany,DC=com',
    searchFilter: (sAMAccountName={{username}})
  }
};
```

The problem is in order for it to work the user authenticating has to have logon privileges to the server hosting ldap. This cannot be correct. Our network/AD guys are new to LDAP so I have to figure this out (I am a software developer so excuse my ignorance).

Everyone is a domain user.

I have 2 demo accounts that are able to authenticate. They are domain users but don't appear to be users on the machine. I can't figure out the difference between the 2 demo accounts that basically have no membership except domain users and other users that are domain users but can't authenticate.

Windows 2012 R2.

Gina

Comment: `Our network/AD guys are new to LDAP`. LDAP is fundamental to AD so I don't see how it's possible an "AD person" is "new" to it. If an error is occurring, it would be helpful to include that, and also the error that occurs on the domain controller when it fails, and the version of Windows/Active Directory domain/forest.

Comment: @GregAskew Yes, very interesting. We are using Windows 2012R2. The error as far as I can tell is Unauthorized. This is actually the second time I've gone through this. LDAP must not be used much any more or taught. Something is awry. I would appreciate more information on the setup. Is there a log I can look at? I don't see anything in the event viewer.

Comment: What happens when you interactively logon to a workstation/server on the network with the accounts that aren't working?

Comment: @GregAskew Logging on to a computer or vpn in all works. That is all using AD right? Our application uses ldap to authenticate. Our customers have been able to figure this out I am just too embarrassed to ask them how they did it. Note: they are not allowed to logon to the domain controller.

Comment: @GregAskew They may have figured it out (even though they said they haven't made any changes). I will report back.